# Do full time or experienced and highly consistent yogis also fall ill?

Tags: practice, yoga, meditation, sanyasi, yogi

We normal mundane people generally fall ill at least once in a year with fever, cough or other regular illness. Maybe such light illnesses used to be part of the body cycle to regain immunity that I am not sure.

What about someone who is highly experienced, consistent and regular toward their [Yoga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga) and [Meditation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meditation) practice or someone who does yoga meditation full time like yogis who left their mundane life to advance spiritually.

Do such yogis also fall ill regularly if yes what type of illness they face? Do they also face the same fever, cold and cough type illness?

If yes how do they manage their illness?

Comment: Real Yogis are not touched by diseases of any sort. If they are then they are not Yogis.

Comment: Yogis are only humans living in the material world. Every human can get sick.

Comment: @Wikash_: So how do they manage?

Comment: Real yogis never touched by disease. There's a method called kayakalpa. If you learn from a guru how to turn body to kayakalpa  this body defeats 4 things - birth old age disease death